# Rest API sends response as plain string however Content Type is "application/json;charset=UTF-8". How can I readthe response

Tags: json, spring, rest, parsing, jackson

We are consuming a third party rest API that returns a UUID as a response to a POST request. The MediaType of the response is `application/json`, however the returned uuid is returned as plain text and **not** as a JSON like `"7c49cec7-8ae8-44c8-bc27-866b6efcfe59"` (with quotes).
I have attached MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to the Spring RestTemplate.
It appears(I'm not sure) that since content type is `application/json` it tries to parse it as JSON and fails to parse it because it doesn't contain double quotes.
Following is the exception

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): Expected space separating root-level values; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]
```

Code:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
  String uuid = restTemplate.postForObject("/order", orderDTO, String.class);
    assertThat(uuid).isNotNull();
}
```

How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: I think you just read it as String

Comment: How? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following solution. It works, but it also forces the conversion of all other media type `application/json` responses to be handled by `StringHttpMessageConverter` instead of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.
I added an interceptor which intercepts the reponse before converting it and then modifies the content type.

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
messageConverters.add(converter);

StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
stringHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(List.of(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
messageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);

restTemplate
        .getInterceptors()
        .add(
                (request, body, execution) -> {
                    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
                    response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                    return response;
                });
```

Comment: We later convinced the provider to fix this bug on their side.